# Are Cheap and rich general opinion adjectives?

Tags: adjectives, adjective-order

> He's a rich unfriendly man.
> He's an unfriendly rich man.

I'm confused two sentences above. Can you help me? Which one is correct?
Thank you, guys!

Answer (score 2):

Cheap is a descriptive adjective.

Rich and Unfriendly are not general opinion but specific opinion adjectives. They (usually) describe *people*. So both your sentences are grammatically correct.

But they would only be idiomatic in certain contexts.

"They're all rich men."
"Yes, but he's an *unfriendly* rich man!"

"They're all unfriendly men."
"Yes, but he's a *rich* unfriendly man!"

[This page](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/english-grammar-reference/adjective-order) might be useful.

Comment: Thank you very much!